# Unable to remove UIButtons and Labels.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been having a strange issue with UIButtons and UILabels in my Swift Game. The user starts out in the game, and upon losing, is moved into a gameover screen. On this gameover screen, their high score is displayed as well as two buttons to either go back to the main menu, or go back to playing the game. This is where the issue arises. Randomly, anytime the scene changes from the gameover scene back to the gameplay scene, the buttons and labels of the gameover scene sometimes do not go away. They stay as static representations of what they were as an overlay over the rest of the game.

I have no idea what could be causing them to disappear most of the time, and then randomly decide to stay around a different time.

Here is the code of the gameover scene. So far I've tried removing the buttons and labels with .removeFromSuperview(), .alpha = 0, and the way the code is now with .hidden = true. None of these work 100% of the time. I've tried everything I could think of but I have no clue what is causing the labels and buttons to stick around.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
class endScene : SKScene {
    var RestartBtn : UIButton!
var scoreLabel = UILabel()
var highLabel = UILabel()
var menuButton = UIButton()
var Highscore : Int!
var HS : Int!
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    RestartBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width/3, height: 30))
    RestartBtn.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.width/1.3)
    RestartBtn.setTitle("Restart", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    RestartBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    RestartBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Restart"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width/3, height: 30))
    menuButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.width/4)
    menuButton.setTitle("Main Menu", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    menuButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("gotoMenu"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(menuButton)
    self.view?.addSubview(RestartBtn)
    self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)
    let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    bgImage.zPosition = -1
    bgImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(bgImage)
    let ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let Score = ScoreDefault.valueForKey("Score") as! NSInteger
    let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    Highscore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as? NSInteger
    if (Highscore != nil){

        HS = Highscore
    }
    else {

        HS = 0
    }
    scoreLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 9, y: view.frame.size.width / 4)
    scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    scoreLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)
    scoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light" , size: 90)
    scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    scoreLabel.sizeToFit()
    highLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 9, y: view.frame.size.width / 2)
    highLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    highLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)
    highLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light" , size: 60)
    highLabel.text = "\(HS)"
    highLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.view?.addSubview(scoreLabel)
    self.view?.addSubview(highLabel)
}
func Restart(){
    running = true
    clearendScene()
    changeSceneGame()
}
func clearendScene(){
    menuButton.hidden = true
    scoreLabel.hidden = true
    highLabel.hidden = true
    RestartBtn.hidden = true
}
func changeSceneGame(){
    self.scene!.view!.presentScene(GameplayScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.8))
}
func changeSceneMenu(){
    self.scene!.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.8))
}
func gotoMenu(){
    clearendScene()
    changeSceneMenu()
}
```

}

[This is a screenshot of the overlay bug happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uwly.png)

[This is a screenshot of how the game is supposed to look on the gameplay scene.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6xjN.png)

Answer (score 0):

From experience I can probably advise you to hide those buttons as immediately as possible. I notice that your hiding them in clearedScene method and embedding that method in both restart and goToMenu. However, where you're calling the clearScene should probably be right before you even invoke the transition.

for example:

```
        func changeSceneGame(){
    clearEndScene()
    self.scene!.view!.presentScene(GameplayScene(), transition:       SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.8))
}
```

Comment: I just tried that. It didn't work. It's such a weird bug, nothing I can see could be causing it.

Comment: since youre using sprite kit why not use those images that you're using as buttons and instead create them as SKLabel Nodes. So that when the user touches that specific button you can just unparent that specific SKlabel

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your endScene is being presented twice (or that didMoveToView gets called twice for some reason) ?

The way your code is written, a second presentation of the endScene will create a new set of buttons and lose track of them leaving only the view holding references to them.

One lazy way of fixing the issue would be to hide the two buttons at the start of didMoveToView.  Since you are creating empty instances of the variables, this should work even the first time.

(you do realise that you're leaking these buttons every time you present endScene right?)

[EDIT]

I guess the lazy way doesn't work because the first time, the instances of UIButton() aren't connected to anything.

You'll need to not be lazy and fix the design.

1) Your button variables should not create empty instances in their declaration.

2) You should not create a new instance of the buttons every time didMoveToView unless you remove them from the view at some point (see below). Your code adds new button objects to the view every time and never releases them.

3) when you do  RestartBtn = UIButton(frame: CG...  you are losing the reference to the previous button you added to the view.  This is why, a second call to didMoveToView without going through Restart() or gotoMenu() will leave button objects showing.

4a) if you want to keep adding buttons in didMoveToView(), remove them from their superview using removeFromSuperview() in an override of func willMoveFromView().

4b) if you want to add them just once and only use their hidden property to show/hide them. make your button variables static,  initialize them to nil and only create and add them once (i.e. when the variables are nil when didMoveToView() is called).

Note: Because something is presenting your endScene twice, all of this may be moot and may not solve the issue.  Perhaps you should set a breakpoint at the beginning of didMoveToView and check the call stack on the first and second call.  This should reveal where the second call comes from (or it could be the first one that's extraneous).

Comment: Before trying to just hide the buttons, I used removefromSuperview() but that caused the same issue. I just tried the lazy way you described and it gave me a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error on the first RestartBtn.hidden = true. And I'm confused to how it could be a second presentation of endScene if it only happens randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my game. So I was setting constraints, initializing my scene (which had the `UIButton`) and presenting it in the `override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. For some reason, this function gets called twice. As Alain T. said, there was a memory leak because of that.

To fix this, I moved all of my code for initialize the scene and present it into `viewDidLoad()` and changed `override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()` to

`override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
 }`

And it worked! The button was gone!